# Save a file with nodejs to external server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

So i have set up a basic nodejs server using express and everything works fine. I have a json file in my folder that i want to be able to modify, to add some data or remove some.

What is the best way to do that without the user being able to interact with the actual file? Perhaps a database that i could send my data to?

I am very new to nodejs and javascript so anything that is as simple as possible is the best.

Comment: Seems like you need some type of versioning. I recommend checking out [git](https://git-scm.com/)

Comment: The official express tutorial under _Getting started_ on expressjs.com will get you up and running with a simple html/javascript frontend and basic routing in the backend. It shows how to do it both from scratch as well as with the tool `express-generator` that will get you started quickly. Once this is done, the answer given by @SerShubham below describes the additional steps required.

Answer (score 1):

You could create different http routes for setting and fetching data in the json file.

Say, for example:

GET /data would read the json file and respond with the contents of the file. 
POST /data could post the contents of the file. 
PUT /data/key could be used to modify the contents of one single key in the json.

That being said, this looks like something that you should be using a DB for. If somewhere down the line, you choose to dockerize your app, everytime you restart your server, your JSON file would be reset to the initial config. 
To avoid that, a db could be used. Mongo is a good place to start considering your choice of language and nature of your data.

Hope you find this helpful :)